# Quick release cannot be tightened

Tags: quick-release, skewer

I had to patch a flat yesterday and now my quick release won´t tighten up anymore. It makes a ratchet Sound when I turn it trying to tighten it. I remember it was hard to loosen the quick release when I removed the wheel yesterday. Any ideas?

The quick release is in pretty pristine condition so I thought I would ask advice before replacing it outright.

Comment: What happens when you remove skewer and try to tighten nut on the other end of skewer? Did you check thread, maybe it is striped? Is QR lever moving properly?

Comment: I can´t remove the nut on the end of the skewer for some reason. It doesn´t screw in either direction but makes a strange ratcheting noise. The QR Lever works fine.

Comment: Sounds like the threads on that one end have become stripped or severely cross threaded

Comment: How are you tightening the QR?  The word "turning" makes me wonder if you're using it right.   The QR lever should be in the Open position while you tighten the nuts by hand, and the flip the QR lever so it clamps up.  I've seen QR levers used like folding wing-nuts and that's not right.

Comment: @Criggie: That's the reason for 'lawyer lips' on front forks, too many people don't know how to operate QRs. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the thread of your skewer and/or the end nut is stripped ... as an emergency measure you could try inserting a slotted washer (see below) under the nut so that the QR can be tightened again, but for a proper repair, you'll need to get a replacement skewer.

[image]